# Probability - Poisson Process and Conditional Expectation

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

Suppose that $N=\{N(t); t \geq 0\}$ is a Poisson Process, with the intensity $\lambda$.
a. Find the probability that the value $N(t)$ is odd (at a given time $t$)

b. Find the conditional expectation of $N(t)$ given that $N(t)$ is odd.

My research into the problem:
a.
$$P[N=\text{odd number}] = e^{-\lambda t}\Bigl[\lambda t+\frac{(\lambda t)^3}{3!} + \frac{(\lambda t)^5}{5!}\ldots\Bigr] =e^{-\lambda t}\sinh(\lambda t).$$

b. I'm having the most trouble with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For (b), use the identity $E[N_t\mid N_t\ \text{odd}]=E[N_t;N_t\ \text{odd}]/P[N_t\ \text{odd}]$ with 
$$
E[N_t;N_t\ \text{odd}]=\sum\limits_{n\geqslant0}(2n+1)P[N_t=2n+1],
$$
and
$$
P[N_t\ \text{odd}]=\sum\limits_{n\geqslant0}P[N_t=2n+1].
$$
and the fact that $P[N_t=n]=\mathrm e^{-\lambda t}(\lambda t)^n/n!$ for every $n\geqslant0$.